# Возникает ошибка типов: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы, type-error

Я новичок в питоне, так что не ругайте.
Возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NNN", line 30, in <module>
    c = 5 - max(s)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'
```

понимаю что float это не complex, но исправить не могу

Код:

```
a = 50.0
b = 25.0
c = 0.0
u = 1
V = 0
t = 0

lis = []

for i in input().split(')'):
    lis.append([float(f) for f in i.replace('(', '').replace(',', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split()])
lis.pop()

tvs = []
pvs = []

for i in lis:
    tvs.append((4 * 3.14 * ((i[0] / 2) ** 3)) / 3)
    pvs.append(round(i[1] / 1000, 6))

s = []
tf = []
for i in range(len(tvs)):
    if pvs[i] >= tvs[i]:
        tf.append(True)
    else:
        tf.append(False)
        s.append((tvs[i] - pvs[i] * 3 * 3.14 / 4) ** (1 / 3))

c = 5 - max(s)
V = a * b * c

for i in tf:
    if i:
        V -= tvs[i]
    else:
        V -= pvs[i]

t = V/u*60

print(lis)
print(tvs)
print(pvs)
print(s)
print(tf)
print(t)
```

входные данные: [(1.593, 812.848), (0.778, 415.376), (0.268, 10.66), (0.675, 182.241), (1.143, 535.905), (1.093, 710.565), (0.575, 37.872), (0.073, 0.232), (0.603, 85.764), (1.287, 645.89)]

Comment: Тут понятно, что ошибка вызывается функцией max, у меня вопрос по поводу строки s.append((tvs[i] - pvs[i] * 3 * 3.14 / 4) ** (1 / 3)), ошибка появляется в ней, что она по задумке программы должна выводить? я не смог понять.

Comment: При возведении выражения в степень (1/3) оно становиться комплексным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас для некоторых значений выражение `(tvs[i] - pvs[i] * 3 * 3.14 / 4)` получается отрицательным.

Во-первых, убедитесь, должно ли быть так. Возможно, у вас там пропущены скобки и должно быть что-то вроде `((tvs[i] - pvs[i]) * 3 * 3.14 / 4)`

Но если вам всё-таки действительно нужно извлекать кубический корень из отрицательного числа, то возводить отрицательные числа в дробную степени - не очень хорошая идея, т.к. float-представления дробей не эквивалентны дроби в математическом смысле, и при возведении в степень это проявляется особенно ярко.

Если нужно извлекать кубический корень из отрицательного числа, то используйте такую функцию:

```
def cube_root(x):
    sign = 1 if (x >= 0) else -1
    return sign * (abs(x) ** (1/3))
```